# How can I build Yocto image to using build script?

Tags: makefile, build, yocto, recipe, build-script

I need to compile some of program in Yocto and this program compile by build script.
Build script doing make(using MakeFile).

As we know, if we don't using bitbake, Yocto need SDK tools. But I can't using SDK tools. So I have to build by recipe.

It is too complicate to using cmake or oe_runmake(for me).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use oe_runmake as it will handle cross-compilation and other stuff for you. You can use devtool to help you create recipe. If makefile is done correctly, recipe is straightforward.